# Loop vector return in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm writing a function that should calculate the following of a vector of numbers (1 - x)^2. However, my function returns zeros and I don't know why:

```
ban <- function(x){
  res <- vector(mode = "numeric", length(x))
  for(i in x) 
    { res[i] <- (1 - res[i])^2}
  return(res)
}
```

input: `ban(c(0.5, 0.6))` gives output: `[1] 0 0`. Why is the output zeros?

Comment: It should be `for(i in seq_along(x))` to index along the vector x.

Answer (score 2):

Your `res`-vector is initialized with zeros. You can see that with:

```
vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(c(0.5, 0.6)))
# [1] 0 0
```

Further in your `for`-loop you loop over `x` and use this to access the entries in `res`. But your `x`-vector contains non-integer values so the access does not work:

```
res <- c(1, 2)
res[0.5]
# numeric(0)
```

In `R` you can do calculations on vectors like that

```
x <- c(0.5, 0.6)

(1-x)^2
# [1] 0.25 0.16
```

so you don't need a for-loop here.

Comment: ah, yes I know it's easier done without a loop, but for the exercise in my class we were asked to do it with a loop :)